# Total Price update from multiple selections using data-* attribute

Tags: jquery, html

so I'm trying to make a simple script that can update the total price from multiple selections. Prices are set in each option using the data-* attribute.

I manage to make it work if i put the prices in the value attribute but somehow not working using the data-price attribute to set the price.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Initial Price: <span id="thisIsOriginal" class="">$62.00</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Total: <span id="total">$62.00</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <select class="optionPrice" name="select-1">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option data-price="" value="1">option a</option>
      <option data-price="20.00" value="2">option b (+$20.00)</option>
    </select>

    <select class="optionPrice" name="select-2">
      <option value="0">Please Select</option>
      <option data-price="5.00" value="3">option c</option>
      <option data-price="10.00" value="4">option d (+$10.00)</option>
    </select>

    <select class="optionPrice" name="select-3">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option data-price="" value="5">option e</option>
      <option data-price="15.00" value="6">option f (+$15.00)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.optionPrice').change(function() {

  var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
  var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(0, 1);
  OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(1);

    var total = 0;

    $('.optionPrice').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('data-price') != 0) {
          total += parseFloat($('option:selected',this).attr('data-price'));
        }
    });
    var newTotal = parseFloat(OriginalPrice) + parseFloat(total);
    $('#total').text('$' + newTotal.toFixed(2));
});
});
```

Demo [here](http://www.bootply.com/1L4oyPbKgP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.optionPrice').change(function () {
        var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text().replace('Initial Price: ','');
        var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(0, 1);
        OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(1);
        var total = 0;
        $('.optionPrice').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price') != 0 && $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price') != undefined) {
                console.log($('option:selected', this).attr("data-price"));
                total += parseFloat($('option:selected', this).attr('data-price'));
            }
        });
        var newTotal = parseFloat(OriginalPrice) + parseFloat(total);
        $('#total').text('$' + newTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm debugging this code, it looks like you are iterating on each select after one has changed which is making undefined values.

I provided version without unnecessary .each. Also I did small cleanup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var originalPriceText = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
    var originalCurrency = originalPriceText.substring(0, 1);
    var originalPrice = originalPriceText.substring(1);
    var total = 0;

    $('.optionPrice').change(function(e) {
        dataPrice = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
        if(dataPrice != undefined && dataPrice.length != 0) {
            total += parseFloat(originalPrice) + parseFloat(dataPrice);
        }
        $('#total').text('Total: $' + total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was for `OriginalPrice`, also there was some problem in `each` block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.optionPrice').change(function() {

      var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
      var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(0, 1);
      OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.split(' ')[2].substring(1);      

        var total = 0;

        $('.optionPrice').each(function() {
          var $el = $(this).find('option:selected');

          if($(this).val() != 0 && typeof $el.attr('data-price') != 'undefined') {
              total += parseFloat($el.attr('data-price'));
          }
        });
        var newTotal = parseFloat(OriginalPrice) + parseFloat(total);
        $('#total').text('$' + newTotal.toFixed(2));
    }); 
});
```